# how to add multiline edittext with image background and shadow

Tags: android

I am new in android i want to add edittext multiline 
and with shadow back side of the edit text how can i do that.

```
      <Edittext
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Comment: by elevation you can drop a shadow and by inputtype you can set multiline .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do line this :

```
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:layout_width="150sp"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="<number of line>"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<Edittext
    android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
    android:layout_width="150sp"
    android:hint="User Name"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:minLines="3"
    />
```

if you want background image and shadow then use,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Edittext
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minLines="3"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```